Proving the spectrum of an operator defined over a finite dimensional space is the set of eigenvalues.
I am trying to understand why the spectrum of an operator $T$ defined over $\mathbb{C}^N$ is precisely the set of eigenvalues.
My first thoughts are that for an eigenvalue, $\lambda,$ $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible because $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$ has nontrivial solution. Therefore, we know that the resolvent in this case does not exist. But I assume there is more to this proof?

$\lambda$ is in the spectrum if $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, and an eigenvalue if $A-\lambda I$ is not injective. In finite dimensional normed spaces, the two are equivalent.
